# css animation expand button content

Tags: html, css, button, css-animations

how can I create  a button animation like this using css?

[what I want to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WDFf5.png)

I want to display only first letter of button, and when hover it expands and shows rest of letters.

maybe something like:

```
<button>h<span>ello</span></button>
```

and css:

```
button {
   width: 40px;
   height: 40px;
   border-radius: 50%;
}

button span {
   display: none: /* maybe hide it first? */
}
```

but when I change the width it looks like a stretched circle because the radius. Whats the best approach to modify the width but keep the same border radius?

Thanks,

AH.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using a nested `<span>`, I recommend using the [`:after` CSS selector](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_after.asp), to show the rest of the button's label. You will want to use [CSS3 transitions](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_transitions.asp) for a smooth hover animation. I combined the `:after` selector with the transition, and a `:hover` opacity of 1, so that the button text appears simultaneously as the button expands.

```css
button {
   width: 50px;
   height: 50px;
   border-radius: 10px;
   padding:6px;
   background-color:black;
   color:white;
   font-size:1.03em;
   box-shadow:3px 3px red;
}
button:hover {
   width:100px;
   height:50px;
   border-radius: 10px;
   padding:6px;
   background-color:black;
   color:white;
   transition:all 0.4s ease 0s;
   font-size:1.02em;
   box-shadow:3px 3px blue;
}

button span {
   opacity: 0;
}
button:hover span {
   opacity: 1;
   transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
}
button:hover span:after {
   content:"ello!";
}
```

```html
<button>H<span></span></button>
```

Comment: Thank you Tanner for the help, cool snippet, gonna steal it :)

Comment: Hello, your example is really good, but I can see a small jump in the first letter when you hover it, its because the padding?

Comment: @Adbullah H. no you dummy, it is because the text-align, if I align it left and play with the padding it look nice :)

Comment: I see you've changed the width from 50 to 100px, but what if the text in the button is dynamic, I wouldn't know the length of the text. .

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you shouldn't use `border-radius` of `50%`, that would make an oval when the width is larger than its height, you should use a fixed value, such as `30px`.

Secondly, you shouldn't fix `height` and `width`, you should set the `padding`, so that the text won't run out of the button.

Thirdly, to change the content, you could use the `content` property.

In the code, I used `:after`, which adds "ello" after "H" on `:hover`.

```css
button {
   padding: 15px;
   border-radius: 30px;
}

button:hover:after {
    content: "ello";
}
```

```html
<button>H</button>
```

Comment: Looks like I got a lot to learn yet :) thank you for helping!

Comment: Excuse me, if I use :after how can I use css transitions to make it smooth?

Answer (score 0):

You can define a `border-radius` value in `px`, `em`, or `rem`. Using `%` will create an ellipse.

You can avoid additional markup by using the `::first-letter` attribute.

Example...

```css
button {
  background: black;
  color: transparent;
  font-size: 3rem;
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 2.5rem;
  width: 5rem;
  height: 5rem;
  padding: .5rem 1.5rem;
}

button::first-letter {
  color: white;
} 

button:hover {
  width: auto;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<button>Hello</button>
```

Comment: Thank you for the insight!, I didn't knew of that selector, TIL.

Answer (score 0):

Simple Use of the :hover tag below /

CSS:

```
.button {
  background-color: pink;
}

.button:hover {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

HTML:

```
<h3 class="button"> Hello, World! </h3>
```